# How should I care for these plants?

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors, plant-care

I moved to a new apartment recently and the owner left me some of his plants.

1. Looks like some citrus plant:

[image]

  2.

[image]

[image]

3. This one already started to rot:

[image]

It will be great to be able to identify them and to know how to care for them: should I keep them on the sunny side, how often should I pour them?

Comment: One question per plant please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first plant is a croton.  See [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/10960/which-plant-is-this-dead-ends-pruning-watering-tips/10961#10961) or [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8606/what-are-these-3-foot-tall-plants-in-southwest-florida/8608#8608) for details.

Second plant bears a passing resemblance to a [clerodendrum bungei](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/15021/trying-to-identify-this-flowering-shrub/15024#15024) but I am not 100% sure.

The third plant is a cactus which is dead from root rot. Best to move it along or cut the new growth off to propagate it. See this [answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5488/cultivating-a-cactus-from-cutting/5505#5505) for details.